Find customers whose yearly total spending is strictly increasing
Unable to formulate the code to find out about the customer_id who have spend more than the previous month. even if the customer took a gap year for example in 2021 he spend $10 in year 2022 he did not spend a single dollar but again in year 2023 he spend $20. this shall mean than the customer have increased their total spending.
I am unable to understand how to approach the question in order to write the correct SQL code.
I first created a table and calculated all the yearly spending of each customer from 2021 till 2024. THIS provided as with year wise spending for each year for each customer.
After this I am  bit clueless how to approach the question.
THIS GIVE ME THE YEARLY SPENDING OF ALL THE CUSTOMER
 WITH customer_yearly_spending AS (
  SELECT 
    customer_id,
    EXTRACT(YEAR FROM invoice_date) AS transaction_year,
    SUM(total) AS year_spending
  FROM invoice
  WHERE EXTRACT(YEAR FROM invoice_date) < 2025
  GROUP BY customer_id, EXTRACT(YEAR FROM invoice_date)
  ORDER BY Customer_id, transaction_year
),

IN THIS PART OF THE QUERY I TIRED TO SPREAD OUT THE SPENDING YEAR WISE LIKE SPENDING IN CURRENT YEAR, PREVIOUS YEAR AND NEXT YEAR
yearly_spending_change AS (
  SELECT
    customer_id,
    year_spending,
    LAG(year_spending) OVER (PARTITION BY customer_id ORDER BY transaction_year) AS previous_year_spending,
    LEAD(year_spending) OVER (PARTITION BY customer_id ORDER BY transaction_year) AS next_year_spending
FROM customer_yearly_spending
)

FOR THE LAST PART I TIRED TO SELECT THOSE CUSTOMER_ID WHERE PREVIOUS YEAR SPENDING IS LESS THAN NEXT YEAR SPENDING.
SELECT 
    customer_id
  FROM yearly_spending_change
WHERE previous_year_spending < year_spending AND year_spending < next_year_spending
GROUP BY customer_id;

The outcome I am getting from the above query:



customer_id




9


30


34


47


50


51


55



The expected outcome should be



customer_id




8


9


29


30


35


46


47


50


51




You should take into account that the LAG/LEAD functions give NULL values for the first/last row of partition.
